# Redeeming Azure code, receive error: A Windows Azure Pass has already been requested for this Windows Live ID. Limit one per account

Tags: azure

I had an Azure account from my university which expired 7 month ago, which was given for one of my courses, now I got another code for a new Azure account from a different course, but when trying to redeem the code I got the following error:
A Windows Azure Pass has already been requested for this Windows Live ID. Limit one per account.

Does it mean I can only request one and only Azure account for my windows live ID, even if the old Azure account has been expired long time ago, meaning I will have to make a new live ID for this new Azure account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You understand correctly. You have to create another Microsoft Account (a.k.a. Windows Live ID) if you want to redeem another code. This is the only possible way. It is same with **trial** subscription. You can only have 1 trial subscription per Live ID Account.